# Using axis ranges to place labels at arbitrary category

Tags: amcharts4

As you can see in the below image. I want to add custom label ranges for y axis.

[image]

I have followed [this](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/using-axis-ranges-to-place-labels-at-arbitrary-values-or-dates/) tutorial and tried below code but it was not working, Any idea how to use categoryAxis with custom labels?

```
let range0 = categoryAxis.axisRanges.create();
range0.value = "MCR.INV-1";
range0.text = "MCR.INV-1";

let range500 = categoryAxis.axisRanges.create();
range500.value = "MCR.INV-2";
range500.text = "MCR.INV-2";

let range1000 = categoryAxis.axisRanges.create();
range1000.value = "PEV1.INV-1";
range1000.text = "PEV1.INV-1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CategoryAxis ranges use `category`/`endCategory` for placement. Replacing `value` with `category` in your ranges will fix the problem.